# jQuery UI intellisense?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, jquery-ui, intellisense

I have been using (and *loving*) the jQuery intellisense for Visual Studio 2008 (blogged about by Scott Guthrie [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx)) but has any one ever come across an intellisense script for the [UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) components of jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this](http://theruntime.com/blogs/jaykimble/archive/2009/07/20/jquery-ui-visual-studio-intellisense-vsdoc-file.aspx)

Comment: It's bad practice to put a link in a post and not have the link text read what you're about to click on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is one. I read the [jQuery UI user group](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui) fairly regularly, and I haven't seen one. The only thing I could find in the archive is a message about [trying to make VS2008 skip over it.](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui/browse_frm/thread/525c04ed90c6003f/64b24c6de473b429?lnk=gst&q=intellisense#64b24c6de473b429).